# arXiv API problem with searching for two keywords

Tags: python

I am trying to use the arXiv API as specified here: https://arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual#Quickstart

Specifically, I am interested in using Boolean operators to search for articles that contain multiple keywords, this is also an example in the quickstart, namely the URL is then: http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=all:electron+AND+all:proton

When I try to do the same and just replace the words by `tracking` and `mapping` and search in the abstracts `abs` (the same error happens with `all` but this example is cleaner) I use the following query: https://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=abs:tracking+AND+abs:mapping
However, the first entry's abstract does not contain both words. Can someone give me a hint where I am going wrong here. I am sorry for this somewhat trivial question, but this is exactly why I am kind of baffled by the result.

First few lines of arxiv response

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <link href="http://arxiv.org/api/query?search_query%3Dabs%3Atracking%20AND%20abs%3Amapping%26id_list%3D%26start%3D0%26max_results%3D10" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  <title type="html">ArXiv Query: search_query=abs:tracking AND abs:mapping&amp;id_list=&amp;start=0&amp;max_results=10</title>
  <id>http://arxiv.org/api/Jsd5/v0H/fvgM23rIIqDByHm7ac</id>
  <updated>2021-08-31T00:00:00-04:00</updated>
  <opensearch:totalResults xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">1587</opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:startIndex xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">0</opensearch:startIndex>
  <opensearch:itemsPerPage xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">10</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry>
    <id>http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3262v1</id>
    <updated>2010-02-17T13:24:32Z</updated>
    <published>2010-02-17T13:24:32Z</published>
    <title>Two-track categories</title>
    <summary>  We describe a 2-dimensional analogue of track categories, called two-track
categories, and show that it can be used to model categories enriched in 2-type
mapping spaces. We also define a Baues-Wirsching type cohomology theory for
track categories, and explain how it can be used to classify two-track
extensions of a track category D by a module over D.
</summary>
    <author>
      <name>David Blanc</name>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>Simona Paoli</name>
    </author>
    <link href="http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3262v1" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
    <link title="pdf" href="http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3262v1" rel="related" type="application/pdf"/>
    <arxiv:primary_category xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom" term="math.AT" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="math.AT" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="math.CT" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="18G55" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://arxiv.org/abs/2003.01755v2</id>
    <updated>2020-10-09T17:13:40Z</updated>
    <published>2020-03-03T19:36:18Z</published>
    <title>Train track maps for graphs of groups</title>
    <summary>  We define train track maps for graphs-of-groups $\cal G$ and exhibit the
precise conditions under which the fundamental finiteness properties known for
classical train track maps extend to this generalization. These finiteness
properties are the crucial tool to control the decrease of illegal turns under
iteration of the train track map, and they are a principal ingredient in the
answer to basic algorithmic questions about automorphisms induced by such train
track maps on $\pi_1 \cal G$.
</summary>
    <author>
      <name>Martin Lustig</name>
    </author>
    <arxiv:comment xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom">This is a completely new article (now 22 pages) with much more
  detailed statements and proofs, a main theorem that applies also to free
  products, and with a detailed description of the algorithm in a new section.
  In the last section an interesting example is given</arxiv:comment>
    <link href="http://arxiv.org/abs/2003.01755v2" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
    <link title="pdf" href="http://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.01755v2" rel="related" type="application/pdf"/>
    <arxiv:primary_category xmlns:arxiv="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom" term="math.GR" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="math.GR" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
    <category term="Primary 20F, Secondary 20E, 57M" scheme="http://arxiv.org/schemas/atom"/>
  </entry>
```

Cheers
Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here!

Essentially, it seems that there is a fuzzy-matching done under the hood by arXiv. Despite "tracking" not appearing explicitly, we see "track":

> We describe a 2-dimensional analogue of **track** categories, called
> two-track categories, and show that it can be used to model categories
> enriched in 2-type
> **mapping** spaces. We also define a Baues-Wirsching type cohomology theory for track categories, and explain how it can be used to
> classify two-track extensions of a track category D by a module over
> D.

This is enough for the API to say that there is a correspondance. I also had that problem for "generative" and "generated", verbs and adjective and nouns...

Another similar issue is that arXiv's API seems to struggle with words in a chain like: "track mapping". In that case, the API would look for both words independently.

For either, the solution seems to be to use double quotation marks `"`. You would need to enclose the phrase in double quotation marks.

[image]

Comment: Hi @marine-galantin and thanks for the answer, I did not expect a response anymore :)